# How to use HWIOAuthBundle with localized sites?

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0, hwioauthbundle

I have a Symfony app available in two locales (fr/en). I used HWIOAuthBundle to connect my users using the GenericOAuth2ResourceOwner. The problem is that when the user is browsing the site in english and connects using Oauth he is then redirected to the site in french which is the default locale. This happens because I loose the locale when the person leaves the site to connect to the service.

I found this question about the same problem but using GoogleResourceOwner: [Smfony2 : HWIOauthBundle : Using multiple locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197711/smfony2-hwioauthbundle-using-multiple-locales)

The solution doesn't work for me but I think it's because the configuration is different for this resource owner. I also thought about setting the locale on the session or on a cookie but I think it's just a workaround.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem with the generic 2 resource owner?

Here's my current configuration.

config.yml:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names:         [secured_area]
    resource_owners:
        my_resource_owner:
            type:                oauth2
            client_id:           "%oauth_client_id%"
            client_secret:       "%oauth_client_secret%"
            access_token_url:    https://external.url/oauth2/token
            authorization_url:   https://external.url/oauth2/authorize
            infos_url:           https://external.url/oauth2/userinfo
        scope:               "read"
        user_response_class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse
        paths:
            identifier: id
            nickname:   username
            realname:   fullname
            email:      email
```

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
   secured_area:
       anonymous: ~
       oauth:
           resource_owners:
               my_resource_owner: "/check-oauth" 
           login_path:        /oauth
           use_forward:       false
           failure_path:      /oauth

           # using default hwi oauth provider
           oauth_user_provider:
               service: hwi_oauth.user.provider
```

Thanks.